# How to click an html tag by href value, puppeteer?

Tags: html, puppeteer

I'm trying to click on a button by the href value, the problem is that the value is variable. See an example below:

```
<a data-v-1615fd2d data-v-7c46ae33
   href="/app/applications/2774009/applicants/3948813" 
   class="applicant-name btn btn-link obs-link">
</a>
```

The numbers in the href are different depending on which file I am trying to select.
Currently, I am clicking buttons with href using the code below:

```js
await page.click("a[href$='someValue']");
```

I would like to do something like this:

```js
let applicationLink= "/app/applications/2774271/applicants/3949188";
await page.click("a[href$='${applicationLink}']");
```

Passing the variable into the `page.click` function.

But this doesn't seem to work.

I am new to this and don't have much experience. Would love some help. Feel free to ask any questions for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to interpolate a variable into a string, you need [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Also, the `$` sign before `=` seems unneeded.

```js
let applicationLink = "/app/applications/2774271/applicants/3949188";

await page.click(`a[href='${applicationLink}']`);
```

Answer (score 1):

[vsemozhebuty is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68319870/6243352) that your template literal is missing backticks, but there's potentially a bit more to it so I'll add some minimal examples that might help your case. If they don't, please provide more information about the site you're manipulating.

Specifically, the `<a>` you show has only whitespace as text. That's not necessarily selectable by Puppeteer as the following snippet shows:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `
    <a href="/app/applications/2774009/applicants/3948813">
    </a>`;
  const applicationLink = "/app/applications/2774009/applicants/3948813";

  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.click(`a[href$="${applicationLink}"]`);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

The above code throws `Error: Node is either not clickable or not an Element` (or: `Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`, depending on your version) on the `page.click()` call. The reason is that Puppeteer [moves the virtual mouse over to the link, then clicks it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50032302/6243352), but the link is zero width so there's no target to click on.

In the example above, if you add some text content to the `<a>`, like `<a href="...">foo</a>`, or add CSS to give it a visible bounding box (minimally, `style="width: 2px; height: 2px; position: absolute;"`), then `page.click()` works.

If the element doesn't have text or size, you can still click it by [using the browser's native `.click()` rather than `page.click()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66537619/6243352) as follows:

```js
let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `
    <a href="/app/applications/2774009/applicants/3948813">
    </a>
    <script>
      document.querySelector("a")
        .addEventListener("click", e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.target.innerText = "clicked!";
        })
      ;
    </script>`;
  const applicationLink = "/app/applications/2774009/applicants/3948813";

  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.evaluate(
    link => document.querySelector(`a[href$="${link}"]`).click(),
    applicationLink
  );
  console.log(await page.$eval("a", el => el.innerText)); // => clicked!
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: There is text content in the selector, I forgot to include it.

Comment: All right, thanks for clarifying. Did fixing the template literal get you moving? If not, maybe a [mcve] would be helpful or a live URL.

Comment: Yes, i found the issue. Thanks